# Change apache user via vhost

Tags: apache, vhosts

I have an Apache 2 server which is shared with several users, who control their own applications. Each application has a virtual hosts (vhost).

Thus, I want to keep the applications of each user on their own /home/ directory. For this, the application files and directories of each user have also to be owned be the user.

So, instead of accessing the application using the default `www-data` user, I want that each vhost uses a different user.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

For each vhost, you have to insert the following directive:

```
AssignUserId <user> <group>
```

inside the `<VirtualHost *:80>` tag. To test if it worked, write a php script like this:

```
<?php
    echo system('whoami');
?>
```

and execute it using your browser.